# ADF Oracle Dynamic Range Partition Option

Tags: azure-data-factory

`POS_TABLE` does not have any partitions. I am using the `ora_hash` function to generate as per the [help documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#parallel-copy-from-oracle). Listed below is the error I keep running into.

> ERROR [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00904: "NUM_RECORDS": invalid identifier.

[image: Configuration setup]

Comment: I think that the Partition column needs to be an actual column that exists in your table, not a derived field. Pretty sure I have ran into this same thing.

Comment: My workaround was to add `mod(ora_hash(STORE_NUM, 4))` to partition column name field. Not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This `[Oracle]ORA-00904` error means that you used an invalid identifier which is mostly an unmatched column name or used an incorrect or unqualified syntax in your statement, however, from your scenario it seems to be as referencing an invalid alias in a SELECT statement.

You are referring the column name [NUM_RECORDS] which does not exists in select , update ,delete ,insert query. Even if you have already aliased a column, but then mistyping the alias later could also cause this error.

Try using the `ora_hash` function alone.

Comment: I added `mod(ora_hash(STORE_NUM, 4))` to the partition column name and it executes.  Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of applying partition of the table using our custom query instead of table load. My approach will be creating two parameters for upperbound and lowerbound value in the pipeline or you can hardcode the range if you know the values. The partition will be on the column NUM_RECORDS, so need to apply the partition condition on this column. Below query will be my source query:

```
select mod(ora_hash(STORE_NUM),4) as NUM_RECORDS
from APP_DB_POS_TABLE
WHERE ?AdfDynamicRangePartitionCondition    
and mod(ora_hash(STORE_NUM),4) <= @pipeline().parameters.upperbound
and mod(ora_hash(STORE_NUM),4) >= @pipeline().parameters.lowerbound
and CNTRY_CD='US'
and BUS_DT >= (sysdate-2)
```